# Drop rows in a group when timestamp is higher then a row with a value in the same group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, list-comprehension

- Consider it is a pandas dataframe **ordered by User and Timestamp**
- See the 1st table - There are two groups of users - User 1 and 2
- The content **Plus** is part of User 1 and comes **after** the content **END** of User 1
- The content **Cast** is part of User 2 and comes **after** the content **END** of User 2

Q: How do I drop **all rows** that could exist **after the content END, based on it's timestamp for each user group** like demonstrating in the 2nd table.

1. Please, **do not understand** that I just want to drop the last row of each group. Imagine that I would have many others.
2. I would **not** like want to use a **loop and if/else** structure for this purpose. Instead, I was trying without success something like this

`df[df['timestamp'] < (df.groupby('user')['timestamp'].transform('max'))]`

But I need to add the content condition (END), and consider the comparisons **IN THE SAME GROUP**. In this case it's been considered the entire `df` timestamp.

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
myDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Content", "User", "Timestamp"], data=[["Airplane", 1, 1515356018],
                                                                           ["Car", 1, 1515356025],
                                                                           ["END", 1, 1515356027],
                                                                           ["Plus", 1, 1515356028],
                                                                           ["Train", 2, 1515356031],
                                                                           ["Trying", 2, 1515356039],
                                                                           ["View", 2, 1515356047],
                                                                           ["END", 2, 1515356050],
                                                                           ["Cast", 2, 1515356055]])

last_considered = myDataFrame["Timestamp"].where(myDataFrame['Content'] == "END").groupby(myDataFrame["User"]).transform("max").astype(int)
to_drop = myDataFrame[myDataFrame['Timestamp'] > last_considered]
to_keep = myDataFrame[myDataFrame['Timestamp'] <= last_considered]
```